# Data alignment: where can it be read off? can it be changed?

Tags: c, optimization, memory

This is exert from a book about data alignment of primitive types in memory.

> Microsoft Windows imposes a stronger alignment requirement—any primitive object of K bytes, for
>   K = 2, 4, or 8, must have an address that is a multiple of K. In particular, it requires that the address
>   of a double or a long long be a multiple of 8. This requirement enhances the memory performance at
>   the expense of some wasted space. The Linux convention, where 8-byte values are aligned on 4-byte
>   boundaries was probably good for the i386, back when memory was scarce and memory interfaces were
>   only 4 bytes wide. With modern processors, Microsoft’s alignment is a better design decision. Data type
>   long double, for which gcc generates IA32 code allocating 12 bytes (even though the actual data type
>   requires only 10 bytes) has a 4-byte alignment requirement with both Windows and Linux.

Questions are:

1. What imposes data alignment, OS or compiler?
2. Can I change it or it is fixed?

Comment: I'd say that it's more the processor that suggests (or in some cases/architectures imposes) good data alignment, the compiler just strives to respect it (and I'd say that the OS is involved only because it's a consumer/producer of data structures used by programs).

Comment: Conclusion: burn the book. It is nonsense.

Comment: The quoted text is nonsense. Both platforms use no-greater-than-4-byte alignment on x86 (32-bit) and 8-byte alignment for `double` and `long long` on x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's the compiler that imposes the alignment. Whenever you declare a primitive type (eg. `double`), the compiler will automatically align it to 8 bytes on the stack.

Furthermore, memory allocations are also generally aligned to the largest primitive type so that you can safely do this:

```
double *ptr = (double*)malloc(size);
```

without having to worry about alignment.

Therefore, generally speaking, if you're programming with good habits, you won't have to worry about alignment. One way to get something misaligned is to do something like this:

```
char *ch_ptr = (char*)malloc(size);

double *d_ptr = (double*)(ch_ptr + 1);
```

---

**There are some exceptions to this**: When you start getting into SSE and vectorization, things get a bit messy because `malloc` no longer guarantees 16-byte alignment.

---

To override the alignment of something, MSVC has the [`declspec(align)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) modifier which will allow this. It's used to *increase* the alignment of something. <strike>Though I'm not sure if it lets you *decrease* the alignment of a primitive type.</strike> It says explicitly that you cannot decrease alignment with this modifier.

---

**EDIT :**

I found the documentation stating the alignment of `malloc()` on GCC:

> The address of a block returned by malloc or realloc in the GNU system
>   is always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems).

Source: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html

So yes, GCC now aligns to at least 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. What about Linux performance? If it's known alignment with multiples of 4 is not optimal anymore can I than change it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the latest versions of GCC on Linux do align to the size of the primitive type as well. So I think the old 4-byte alignment is mostly a thing of the past.

Comment: There are tons of structures that Windows APIs consume or produce and it's pretty bad if one manages to call those APIs with improperly packed/aligned versions of them.

Comment: Interesting, because the book http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Systems-Programmers-Perspective-2nd/dp/0136108040 is of 2010. Are such things documented in GCC docs or one normally is not expected to smth about them.

Comment: I don't know if it's documented or not. But it makes perfect sense for GCC to (silently) do the alignment anyway. The performance penalty of a misaligned access to a `double` is huge on the machines that I've tried. (Note that I haven't actually looked at any GCC-generated assembly to confirm the 8-byte alignment, but I've never noticed a performance degradation between Windows to Linux, so I assume no.)

Answer (score 3):

The x86 CPUs have pretty lax alignment requirements. Most of data can be stored and accessed at unaligned locations, possibly at the expense of degraded performance. Things become more complex when you start developing multiprocessor software as alignment becomes important for atomicity and observed order of events (writing this from memory, this may be not entirely correct).

Compilers can often be directed to align variables differently from the default alignment. There're compiler options for that and special compiler-specific keywords (e.g. `#pragma pack` and others).

The well-established OS APIs can't be changed, neither by the application programmer (the OS is already compiled), nor by the OS developers (unless, of course, they are OK with breaking compatibility).

So, you can change some things, but not everything.

Comment: Please specify compilers where `#pragma pack` can be used.

Comment: Borland, Microsoft, Open Watcom and GNU C/C++ compilers support #pragma pack.

Comment: You can also use the gcc options -mstrict-align -mno-strict-align to control its behavior

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where microsoft got its information from, but the results on 
gcc (4.6.1 Target: x86_64-linux-gnu, standard mode, no flags except -Wall) are quite different:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct lll {
    long l; 
    long long ll;
    };      

struct lld {
    long l; 
    long double ld;
    };      

struct lll lll1, lll2[2];
struct lld lld1, lld2[2];

int main(void)
{   
printf("lll1=%u, lll2=%u\n"
    , (unsigned) sizeof lll1
    , (unsigned) sizeof lll2
    );      

printf("lld=%u, lld2=%u\n"
    , (unsigned) sizeof lld1
    , (unsigned) sizeof lld2
    );      

return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
./a.out
lll1=16, lll2=32
lld=32, lld2=64
```

This might be FUD (from the company that actually managed to put unaligned ints into the MBR ...). But it could also be a result of the author not being informed too well.

To answer the question: it is the hardware that *imposes* the alignment restrictions. The compiler only needs to *implement* them.

Comment: If you're using some fixed APIs where specific alignment/packing is expected (e.g. some Windows API functions that consume or produce structures), you can't use arbitrary alignment/packing. So, the it's not only the hardware.

Comment: Well, that is a windows problem. The unix/linux way is: user code and system code (and thus: the APIs) share *the same* alignment requirements. (*as if* they were compiled by the same compiler with the default settings). Besides: the first N arguments for function calls (and presumably: system calls) are passed via registers, IIRC.

Comment: I'm not so sure about it not being a unix/linux problem. Smart guys may "outsmart" themselves with any OS.

Comment: The only place I can think of where unaligned data could be communicated to/from userspace is network packets and video / CODEC data. (and some ugly binary files from older or different architectures) But these can all be treated as just data; char[xxx].